# mongoid TypeError: keys must be strings or symbols

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

When I run this query in the Rails console:

```
1.9.3p286 :118 > cs = Conference.any_of({:schedule_cache => { :$elemMatch => { :start_date.gte => Date.parse('7 Mar 2013'), :end_date.lte => Date.parse('8 Mar 2013')}}})
1.9.3p286 :118 > cs.count
```

I get:

```
TypeError: keys must be strings or symbols
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using string keys?

```
cs = Conference.any_of({'schedule_cache' => { '$elemMatch' => { 'start_date.gte' => Date.parse('7 Mar 2013'), 'end_date.lte' => Date.parse('8 Mar 2013')}}})
```